# Iframe being removed only for some users when publishing a page

Tags: multisite, pages, wp-admin

I have multi site wordpress installation.

Recently I had a user complaining about not being able to add frames to a page. When I did it it just worked. This user is administrator on this page.

Is there a setting or some embedded rule that only allows the multi site administrator to add this kind of code?

Answer (score 1):

To post most HTML tags (such as `<script>` and `<iframe>`), the user requires the [`unfiltered_html` capability](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html). In WordPress Multisite, this capability is (by default) assigned only to Super Admins (ie, those that can administer the entire network).

This is by design, and is due to security concerns, among other things:

> **Note:** Enabling this option for untrusted users may result in their posting malicious or poorly formatted code.

### Reference

- [Roles and Capabilities » `unfiltered_html`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#unfiltered_html) on the WordPress Codex